# Is it possible in PHP like Java's socksProxyHost?

Tags: php, proxy, socks

Is there any option in PHP to set a socks proxy for incoming and outgoing traffic?

Comment: Well, since php supports raw [sockets](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php), yes you can (You may need to write the proxy yourself, or find another library for it).  But I have to ask.  Why?  What does having it in PHP get you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an option in PHP to set a socks proxy.